# i have installed iperf3 when i use iperf3 with server mode i am getting the following error libcrypto.so.1.1 not found

Tags: openssl, fedora, iperf, fedora16, iperf3

i have installed iperf3 in fedora 15 . When I used "iperf -u -s -V" the following error is shown "iperf3: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I have tried to install openssl 1.1.1 and openssl 1.1.0h but still also i am not able to locate libcrypto.so.1.1

Comment: What method did you use to "install" these software/libraries ?

Comment: I am no sure your question is related to programming. Maybe unix.stackexchange.com would be better suited.

Comment: Yum install doesn't work in my case so i downloaded zip file and i installed

Comment: can you please suggest which openssl version will contain libcrypto.so.1.1